# Why is pointer address different when the variable is unallocated? Unallocated and allocated variable pointer address not same

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Why is the pointer address different when the variable is unallocated?
Why is unallocated variable pointer address a lot larger than allocated variable pointer address?

The output is :

> 0x76d9734a 
>   0x29fee8

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int * pointer;

    cout<<pointer;

    int variable = 12;

    pointer = &variable;

    cout<<endl<<pointer<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: uninitialized `pointer` contains junk

Comment: Uninitialized variables contain garbage. Your `pointer` is uninitialized.

Comment: Could you answer the following similar question by yourself? `int i; cout << i; i = 99; cout << i;`. Why they have different (or equivalent by change) values?

Comment: Therw is no pointer address used anywhere in the program. `int * pointer;  cout<<pointer;` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable without initialising it, it's value is undefined. That means that at first, your pointer contains just some random data that happened to be there when you declared that pointer. Now you declare a variable on the stack and set the pointer to point to it. This means, of course, that the pointer now holds the address of `variable` and not the undefined garbage that used to be there after it's declaration.

Regarding the size of the pointer's value: Since your pointer is uninitialized, it just contains some random bits which are unlikely to point to a valid memory address. When you initialise it, however, it points to a concrete location on the stack. Since the stack lives in a somewhat confined region of memory and is not randomly spread out across the whole address space, the address of `variable` is always going to be in the same ballpark.

Comment: What you are describing is how the OP's implementation handles the situation. As far as C++ is concerned, it's just undefined behaviour, not "random data" or "garbage".

Comment: @ChristianHackl You are right. Still, to describe the behaviour OP is seeing, referring to what the implementation does is quite useful, especially since OP doesn't seem to have a lot of experience with C++.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int * pointer;
>
> cout<<pointer;
> ```

Trying to read from an uninitialised `int*` is undefined behaviour even if you do not dereference it.

This means that the C++ programming language has no rules for what your program should or should not do. All behaviour you have observed should be considered random. You can fix your code by initialising the variable or assigning to it before the first read:

```
int * pointer = /* some valid value */;
```

Or:

```
int * pointer;
pointer = /* some valid value */;
```

Note that `nullptr` is a valid value.